# Cluster with two instances in glassfish creating concurrency error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, glassfish-3

I have two clusters and each cluster have 2 instances. When quartz scheduler is scheduled to run at 11PM in both the clusters of all the 4 instances starting at same time and making my application erroneous. Either cases are processed twice or cases are getting stuck with error.

In my scheduler program i am forming xml from table and sending that xml to web services.

Please let me know if any further information required. Please help me to resolve this concurrency error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file lock technique in the below link helps me

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0288.html